# Moving projects from PVCS into Git

Tags: git, version-control, pvcs

My firm is looking to move projects from PVCS to git but the firm wants all the history, can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can migrate directly but you can migrate to subversion and from subversion migrate to GIT.

google pvcstosvn

Comment: Including a little more information here rather than telling the OP to google something is generally preferred.